# If duplicate between sheets copy row

Tags: excel-2010

I have a dataset in Sheet1 with A being Identifiers and B being extra info. 
If I have a duplicate A anywhere in Sheet2 I want to copy the B from Sheet1 to Sheet2 irrespective of where the duplication occurs in Sheet1 A.

I am currently trying: `=IF(Sheet2!A1=Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$B, 99)`, however this only works row by row and I want it to search all of Sheet1 for duplications and insert the B that belongs to the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to solve by using formules. Probably, you need to create a VBA macros. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213798/en-us?fr=1